# Theos error: "Can't call method "isNew" on an undefined value at /var/mobile/sbtest1/theos/bin/logos.pl line 382."

Tags: objective-c, theos

I was wondering how I would fix this error in the Logos.pl file, this is what I'm getting: 
`WillPhone:/var/mobile/sbtest1 root# make package install
/var/mobile/sbtest1/theos/makefiles/targets/Darwin-arm/iphone.mk:43:                                  Targeting iOS 4.0 and higher is not supported with iphone-gcc. Forcing clang.
Making all for tweak sbtest1...
 Preprocessing Tweak.xm...
Constants from lexical variables potentially modified elsewhere are deprecated at /private/var/theos/bin/lib/aliased.pm line 42.
Constants from lexical variables potentially modified elsewhere are deprecated at /private/var/theos/bin/lib/aliased.pm line 42.
Constants from lexical variables potentially modified elsewhere are deprecated at /private/var/theos/bin/lib/aliased.pm line 42.
Constants from lexical variables potentially modified elsewhere are deprecated at /private/var/theos/bin/lib/aliased.pm line 42.
Constants from lexical variables potentially modified elsewhere are deprecated at /private/var/theos/bin/lib/aliased.pm line 42.
Constants from lexical variables potentially modified elsewhere are deprecated at /private/var/theos/bin/lib/aliased.pm line 42.
Constants from lexical variables potentially modified elsewhere are deprecated at /private/var/theos/bin/lib/aliased.pm line 42.
Constants from lexical variables potentially modified elsewhere are deprecated at /private/var/theos/bin/lib/aliased.pm line 42.
Can't call method "isNew" on an undefined value at /var/mobile/sbtest1/theos/bin/logos.pl line 382.
make[2]: *** [obj/Tweak.xm.a114fd55.o] Error 255
make[1]: *** [internal-library-all_] Error 2
make: *** [sbtest1.all.tweak.variables] Error 2'`˚`

Thanks! - Will B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can go to [Theos Github](https://github.com/codyd51/Theos-Examples) to submit this issue.

Here are some other projects with this issue.I hope it will help you.

https://github.com/preaction/Statocles/issues/190

https://github.com/Crowdtilt/Business-BalancedPayments/issues/53

Comment: Thanks! I'll be sure to file an issue over there.